# Accidentally ran blkdiscard on root drive, screwed?

Tags: linux, ssd

Long story short. I screwed up badly and managed to run blkdiscard on my root drive instead of the intended disk. Am I completely screwed?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed best practice, the only thing of value you have lost is `/etc`. Since `/home`, `/var` and friends are on different partitions, the easiest way to fix is to reinstall and restore `/etc`from backup - this will also link in the existing file systems via fstab.

Comment: I do have backups. /var, /home were on different partitions but on the same drive so restoring will take ages, I was hoping to avoid that. Ah well, lesson learned.. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: If you ran `blkdiscard` only on the root partition, nothing should have happened to thje other partitions

Comment: I ran it on the entire disk (eg /dev/sdx).